# Implementing RFB with SSL without CA

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am trying to implement RFB with SSL for authentication and encryption.

> But SSL requires certificates ( which i don't have since its only
> PC and Android which are communicating, without intermediate server ).
>
> I don't need server authentication instead of that, i need client
> authentication, how to obtain it without using certificates.
>
> If there is no way of getting rid of certificates, is it possible
> to use certificates while communicating between PC and Android,
> if yes then how ?

Getting lost in mid of project, can anyone guide me out ? searched for solution, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want security with SSL, you do need server authentication (you could reverse the roles of the client/server, i.e. have the SSL server be the TCP client and vice versa, but that's probably over-complicated).

If you control the application, a self-signed certificate on the server would work just fine. You could have one for your client too if you want client-certificate authentication as well. It might be more convenient to build a small CA for your application. There are tools to help with that, for example OpenSSL's `CA.pl` or TinyCA.

Once you've generated your server certificate, you'll need to configure your client to trust it. Don't use a `TrustManager` that trusts anything (you may come across some example code for this, including here on SO): this would defeat the purpose of authentication, and make your SSL connection vulnerable to MITM attacks.

Comment: Is it possible to set self-signed certificate on my PC ? Because i am trying to implement Remote desktop sharing app without intermediate server. So is it possible to use SSL between normal PC (Not Server) and Android ?

Comment: Is SSL only meant to be used only with HTTP ? or we can use it for securing communication between PC (running windows xp/Vista/7) and android ?

Comment: Yes, the only problem with self-signed certs (or certs issued by your own CA) is that you'd need to import them explicitly onto your device yourself. You can use SSL between any device your like (provided there is support if you don't want to code the SSL stack yourself), including a PC and an Android device. It can be used in principle for any protocol you'd use over TCP, not just HTTP.

Comment: Okay, any pointers on implementation ? like, how should i begin implementing RFB along with SSL. Because i can find implementation only on HTTP. The basic thing is connection between PC and Android is being done over TCP/IP.